# Encode text in a comparable way

Tags: hash

Let have two text document and we want to compare them on a way that it is not lettered by letter. I am looking for a kind of way that encodes the text into a hash (if the word hash is proper here) of length `N` (256 characters for instance) and allows for comparisons.

For example, let `a='Text1', b='Text 1', c='Text 12'` and `d ='John'`. I want a kind of hashing (here length 5) like this

```
xyztrg
xyutrg
xyvtrg
abcdef
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is locality-sensitive hashing:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality-sensitive_hashing

This technique hashes similar input items into the same "buckets" with high probability.

Depending on which programming language you are using, there are a lot of implementations

Comment: Thanks but this does not answer the question as each single text file must be encoded independent of others

Comment: Locality sensitive hashing can be applied to each single text file, independently from others. The hash function is made so that similar inputs will give with high probability the same hash.